# Vue Advanced Chat - scroll to footer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use vue-advanced-chat component with vue 3

```
"vue-advanced-chat": "^2.0.7", 
"vue": "^3.0.0",
```

I keep the entire object of the selected room `roomSelected`, which contains the `canWriteMessage` parameter, which defines for me whether the user can write and send a message or not.

```
<vue-advanced-chat
...
:show-footer="roomSelected.canWriteMessage"
...
/>
```

I have the entire vue advanced chat component located at the bottom of my website. The page is relatively long, contains article details, gallery, etc. and the chat is located below these data

PROBLEM:

**when the client comes to the site, the page immediately tries to scroll through the entire content and come to the chat**

respectively, the chat component tries to scroll the footer. when I set `:show-footer="false"`, the client stayed up after being added to the page, which I consider correct

Expectation:

it shouldn't be like that, the client should stay up and look at the detail of the article and gradually scroll down

I tried, but it didn't help:

```
autoScroll: {
  send: { new: false, newAfterScrollUp: false },
  receive: { new: false, newAfterScrollUp: false }
},
```

Comment: so far i fixed it like this:
setTimeout(() => {
  this.showChat = true
}, 500)

...which I do not consider to be a very correct solution, but it works, for now